# what does Validator::make($request->all() do in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: forms, validation, laravel

Laravel newbie here. 
I am trying to understand the following snippet, and it's not clearly explained on the Laravel docs. I thought maybe other newbies might also find it helpful if it were explained in plain words. From what I understand, the routes file contains this route for new task creation, and so the validator makes a check on all the fields of the incoming Request object, checking along the way if the name field equals 255 chars? Is that correct? Why do we have a $request->all() bit in there?

```
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Validator::make()` takes two arguments: one array of inputs to check, and one array of rules to check against.

If you have a posted form from a webpage, you can retrieve the form data (and/or GET variables) from the `$request` object. If you want all of them, you simply call `$request->all()`.

So what you're saying in the code is basically "I want to create a new validator. I supply it with the posted form data, and I want to check that form data against these rules. There's only one rule, which says to make sure the name field was supplied, and that it isn't longer than 255 characters."

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful!